# Have the await call on the async method wait until completion

Tags: async-await, rxjs

I have an observable that returns 500 items of a never ending stream of random numbers:

```
public async getSomeMidiNotes(): Promise<Array<number>> {
  const notes: Array<number> = new Array<number>();
  await this.getRandomMidiNotes()
  .pipe(
    take(500)
  )
  .subscribe(note => {
    notes.push(note);
  });
  return notes;
}

public getRandomMidiNotes(): Observable<number> {
  return interval(MIDI_NOTE_DURATION)
    .pipe(
      map(data => Math.floor(Math.random() * MIDI_NOTE_MAX) + MIDI_NOTE_MIN)
    );
}
```

I'm using it to return an array:

```
const gotes: Array<number> = await this.generatorService.getSomeMidiNotes();
console.log(gotes);
```

But the array displayed in the browser console is always of varying length, sometimes 2 items, sometimes 50, etc...

I would like the array to be fully staffed with the 500 items before returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### working code

```
public async getSomeMidiNotes(): Promise<Array<number>> {
  const notes: Array<number> = new Array<number>();

  return getRandomMidiNotes().pipe(
    take(500),
    map(note => {
      notes.push(note);
      return notes;
    })
  ).toPromise();
}
```

Usage:

```
const notes: Array<number> = await this.generatorService.getSomeMidiNotes();
console.log(notes);
```

The stackblitz implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fcmzrp

### Explanations

The `map` function push the items to the array of notes and returns it.
The `toPromise` allows you to convert your observable to a promise. In this case, it returns the promise and when you call `getSomeMidiNotes` you'll be able to use `await`.

Comment: High chaparal after applying your suggestion. The console log displayed the 500 notes once only. And then all page refreshs did not display anything. I tried both `const gotes: Array<number> = await this.generatorService.getSomeMidiNotes();` and `this.generatorService.getSomeMidiNotes().then((gotes) => {
      console.log(gotes);
    });` and no display in the console.

Comment: Not sure about your problem, could you explain how pages show the 500 notes?

Comment: The console logger shows one line for the array and it can be folded down by a mouse click. But it shows this only once and then shows nothing at all. But seeing a logger output is rare, most of the time nothing is shown.

Comment: `this.
getSomeMidiNotes()` get the first 500 notes, it is correctly showing up in console (see my Stackblitze example). Then if you want to use this in multiple pages, you have to call it mutiple time. Note that you have to wait the 500 notes are emitted.

Comment: My mistake, I was not waiting long enough for the promise to resolve. And it would sometimes display the logger of the previous page reload. By having the time interval much lower I can see it works flawlessly.